Alternative (Integral) Definition of the Modified Bessel Function of First Kind and Zero Order
It is known that
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-\frac{x(\alpha\cos\xi+\beta\sin\xi)}{\gamma^{2}}}d\xi = I_{0}\left(\frac{x\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}}{\gamma^{2}} \right).\hspace{0.2in} (\star)
$$
As far as I know, the usual integral definition of the Modified Bessel function of zero order, or at least the one that I found, is the following:
$$ I_{0}(x) :=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{x \cos\xi} d\xi. $$
Does anyone know why the equation $(\star)$ holds and how to prove it? Or have any good reference or textbook material related to it?
Thank you all!

Write $\alpha=r\cos\theta, \beta = r\sin\theta$, where $r^2 = \alpha^2 + \beta^2$, and simplify.

Here is my attempt:
Considering a right triangle with hypotenuse $\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}},$ opposite side $\alpha,$ adjacent side $\beta,$ and angle $\phi$ being the angle opposite to the side $\alpha,$ we know that
$$ -\frac{\alpha x}{\gamma^{2}}\cos\xi  -\frac{\beta x}{\gamma^{2}}\sin\xi  =  \sqrt{\left(-\frac{\alpha x}{\gamma^{2}} \right)^{2}+\left( -\frac{\beta x}{\gamma^{2}}\right)^{2} } \cos(\xi-\phi) \\
= x\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}}{\gamma^{2}}  \cos(\xi-\phi). $$
Therefore, the initial integral gets reduced to an integral with only the cosine trigonometric function on the power of the exponential, which by noticing that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{x\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}{\gamma^{2}} } \cos(\xi-\phi)} {\rm d}\xi = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{x\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}}{\gamma^{2}} } \cos(t)} {\rm d}t,$ and using the definition of the Modified Bessel gives the integral on the right hand side of $(\star).$
